# Какой объект я создаю?

Tags: java, объекты, new

Есть класс `Basket` и `LoyalBasket`, который экстендит `Basket`

Когда я пишу `Basket basket = new Basket();`, я создаю объект Basket.

Какой я объект создаю, когда пишу `Basket loyalBasket = new LoyalBasket();`? Если создается объект Basket, то что тогда обозначает запись `Basket loyalBasket = new LoyalBasket();`? Если создается объект LoyalBasket, то почему я не могу испольовать методы из LoyalBasket?

Посмотрел видео про объекты, но не нашел ответа на свой вопрос.

Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Вы создаете объект типа `LoyalBasket` и записываете ссылку на этот объект в переменную типа `Basket`. При этом вы работаете с объектом на уровне типа `Basket`. В классе `Basket` нет методов из `LoyalBasket`, поэтому их нельзя вызвать. Вы можете тип переменной сделать `LoyalBasket` и тогда будут доступны методы.

Comment: Примерно то же самое происходит, когда вы покупаете Hyundai Solaris, а на работе говорите - я купил машину (не указывая марку), ибо всем в общем то все равно какую машину вы купили (особенно, если это Hyundai Solaris) :)